# REST API - One operation that belongs to two different resource endpoints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, api, restful-architecture

I find myself too many times in front of a situation when I should create two different resources on an API server, that are initiated by one single action. I would call it cross-controller opertaion: an operation that requires logic to be performed in two different controllers

For example, imagine an applicaiton with a `User` model and an `Account` model

User can be associated to multiple accounts.

In my REST API I have an `/accounts/` endpoint and a `/users/` endpoint which are responsible for the `Account` and `User` model respectively, and `/accounts/:account_id/users` endpoint for the assocation between these 2 models

So if a user choose to disassociate itself from an account I make such a request: `HTTP DELETE /accounts/:account_id/users/:id`

When a user registers I obiously `POST /users/` to create a new user

There is also an option for a user to register and get directly associated to an account (by a special invitaion for example). In such case I would have to register a user and create an association to the account being invited to, preferably doing that in a single request to the server.

I know I can do a request to `/users/` in order to create the user and then another request to `/accounts/1/users/1` to create the link between the user and the account, but doing so only to stick to the REST principles seems redundant.

Another option is to create a different action such as `register_from_invitation` that will take care of both action but then the question is where it should sit. In the AccountUsers controller, in the Users controller or in the Accounts controller. This also seems wrong to me.

Any prefered way to solve such a design issue?

Answer (score 1):

I can see several possible solutions.

1. The method that you described (making to requests: first to `/users` and second to `/accounts/...`) is the most REST-full. It is simple, logical and used widely. It may look a little awkward, but it's not. Here you split your logic strictly, not mixing up methods from two controllers.
2. Then, you can always accept requests to `POST /accounts/:account_id/users/`. And here create a new user and bind it to the account. From the outer space of your app it looks good, but *inside* it will cause a slight mix of `User` and `Account` methods in `Account` controller. That's no good.
3. If you still want to have `register_by_invitation` method, you can confidently put it in `Users` controller. Create user there and bind it to some Account you receive in request params.

However, if you want to keep your app RESTfull and do not want to mix the logic from several controllers into one, there's only one I see.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will ask you another question that just popped into my mind: What if I will be able to create the User but then will fail to create the association on the second request to /accounts/:account_id/users? As I see it the User creation and UserToAccount association should be a transactional opertaion.

Comment: @yanivps Being an external person I don't know why this operation could fail, what possible workarounds and consequences exist. But in the first case, I see no problem: you create a user, and respond with success. Then you fail to bind it and respond with the appropriate error. And those, who received the error are to decide what to do. In other cases, you probably want to do it as a transaction, yes, because if the request fails, the sender expects all operations to fail.

Comment: @yanivps  As for me, this is one more reason to use REST-y way: you do not mix errors for the API users, which otherwise are able to contain messages for both `user` and `account`. That's not very atomic.

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding another resource called `UserAccountMembership`. The benefit of this is that you'll separate responsibilities: `User` and `Account` resources will remain clean, and at the same time you'll get a resource where you expose specific information about a "connection" between those two (like date/time of a link creation, active/inactive status etc.):

```
/useraccountmemberships/{useraccountmembershipid} POST, PUT, GET, DELETE

{
    "Id": useraccountmembershipid,
    "UserId": userid,
    "AccountId": accountid,
    "Timestamp": "2018-1-1",
    ...
}
```

You may still want to allow access to memberships via a parent resource, which is fine:

```
/users/{userid}/useraccountmemberships GET
/accounts/{accountid}/useraccountmemberships GET
```

Comment: In the example that is in my question, the /accounts/:account_id/users is the "connection" resource that you are suggesting here. It is also mapped to AccountUsers controller (which is different from Users controller / Accounts controller) in order to keep them clean

Comment: that's fine. however exposing a separate resource is a restful way of "register_from_invitation" option you have